# undefined method `each' for (need short code to treat object collection that works with 'each' and single obj)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Problem:

if returned result single result each method fail - how code can be improved?

The case:

controller action:

```
@results= Person.find_by_name('Ben');
```

view:

```
<% if nil!=@results %>
    <% @results.each do |r| %>
       <h2>courses:</h2> <a href="/course/<%= r.name %>/"><%= r.name %></a>
    <% end %>
<% else %>
       <h2>no results</h2>
<% end %>
```

result:

```
undefined method `each' for #<Person id: 2, name: "Ben">
```

Thanks

Comment: find_by_name will only return 1 answer so you can't loop though it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common idiom is to use `Array()`

```
@results = Array(Person.find_by_name('Ben'))
```

`Array()` will always return something that's enumerable, even if it's nil.

Then you can keep the rest of your code the same. But I would suggest cleaning it up a bit using the rails helper `present?`

```
<% if @results.present? %>
   ....
<% else %>
   <h2>no results</h2>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Chek it with type before you loop:

```
if !@results.is_a?(Person) && !@results.blank?
  # loop through them all as you are doing...
elsif !@results.blank? #still avoiding the possible nil error here
  # print out for a single record
else
  # there are no results
end
```

You always want to make sure its not blank (nil or empty), but the first check assures that you dont have a person object and if its not blank that means ActiveRecord returned an array of person objects for you.

Comment: Type checking is not the typical way things are done in rails/ruby